# Problem with background picture in Feather theme

Tags: beamer, themes

I am using Feather theme for my presentation. I have downloaded it from Overleaf. The original source works properly without any error but it does not show the background picture in the title and last slide. Could someone help me?

Comment: Could you show us by providing a link or code in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)?

Comment: This is the link I have downloaded the theme, https://www.overleaf.com/4332446zgjxbv#/12875770/. I think the problem should be somewhere in the .sty files.

Comment: Does it show the little logo on the other slides?

Comment: No! neither  background nor logo.

Comment: Just to make sure, you compile with `pdflatex` and not say `latex`? Also can you test, if you are able to include other images in the presentation?

Comment: Great! Thanks samcarter. I was using xelatex seems is not compatible with beamer. I changed it to pdflatex and it works now. Thanks

Comment: Good to hear it is working now! However I think, it should also work with `xelatex`, at least with `XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015)` I see no problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you copy the code from overleaf to your own tex program, you miss the stylesheets:
[image]

As you can see the document needs four `.sty` documents also. If you place this in the same directory as your presentation, everything will be ok.

Edit: there is also a folder `\Feathergrapics` with contains 2 documents: `1.pdf` and `2.pdf`. You should make this folder in your document folder.

Comment: Actually I copied 4 .sty files plus the folder of the images in the correct way such that the code recognise the image folder directory. As I said it works with no error. However, the backgrounds in the title slide does not appear.

Comment: I adapted my answer. Everything worked over here. I use TeXPad on OS10

Comment: In fact, I have copied the whole project in the Overleaf with no modification. For example, if I change the name of pic files 1.pdf to 10.pdf then I receive error. But working with original version of the project, I do not receive any error and again with no background picture in the first slide.  I have checked it with texstudio and texmaker in Ubuntu 14.0.

Comment: In beamerinnerthemFeather.sty you have a line                   \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{Feathergraphics/1}
    that "1" refers to the graphic 1.pdf   in beameroutherthemeFeather.sty you have a line (199) \node at (logopos) {\includegraphics[width=1.75\beamer@logoradius]{Feathergraphics/2}}; The "2" in that line refers to 2.pdf.

Comment: Yes! I had found the first one refer to background. Thank you for drawing my attention to the second one refer to the logo. But actually I could not find any resolution for it. Still no figure appears in the logo part and background.

Comment: First attempt... try to rename 1.pdf to 10.pdf in .sty and in de folder. Same with 2.pdf to 20.pdf. If that works, there is something wrong with your images. If it doesn't than there must be another place where the 1.pdf and 2.pdf is defined.

Comment: I know that I'm late in the conversation but when you get an error like this, it's highly likely that you included a package that you do not necessarily need for the tex file to compile. So comment out \usepackage{*} one at a time and your background image should appear.